# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle11g, glassfish, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to configure the file(**sun-resources.xml**) in charge of creating automatically the pool of connections and the data source that will be used for the tests in my project. I am using Glassfish as a server, oracle 11g as the database engine and arquillian for the tests. However when running the file with a test I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found.` Which I do not understand because since the ping from the glassfish administrator everything seems to be fine. I usually do the same configuration but using mysql and it works correctly. What am I doing wrong?

sun-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application
Server 9.0 Resource Definitions //EN"
"http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sunresources_1_3.dtd"
<resources>
<jdbc-connection-pool 
    name="RocsPool"
    datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" 
    res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" >
    <property name="User" value="admin" />
    <property name="DatabaseName" value="database_rocs" />
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <property name="PortNumber" value="1521" />
    <property name="Password" value="12345" />
    <property name="ServerName" value="localhost"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource 
    enabled="true" 
    jndi-name="jdbc/rocs"
    object-type="user" 
    pool-name="RocsPool" />
</resources>
```

arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<container qualifier="glassfish" default="true">
<configuration>
<property name="sunResourcesXml">src/test/resources/sun-resources.xml
</property>
</configuration>
</container>
</arquillian>
```

Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletUtil.determineBaseURI(ServletUtil.java:69)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletURIHandler.locateTestServlet(ServletURIHandler.java:60)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:84)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:136)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:372)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:246)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:260)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:330)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:205)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:219)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```